# .Net Core execute insertion stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-core, entity

i want to insert data into SQL table using stored procedure in MVC it was
`_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("procedure")` which is now obsolete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("procedure") which is now obsolete

For the execution of SQL queries using plain strings, use `ExecuteSqlRaw` instead. For the execution of SQL queries using interpolated string syntax to create parameters, use `ExecuteSqlInterpolated` instead.

Reference:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlinterpolated?view=efcore-3.1
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlcommand?view=efcore-3.1
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql